# Thread Safe Publish Subscribe in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, publish-subscribe

I created a simple set of interfaces and a class that allows me to publish the additions and removals of items in a generic dictionary. Subscribers receive the entire list when they subscribe and after that, they get only the changes.

Although my solutions work, I am looking for something a little more standard, a little less home-grown. Do you have any suggestions?

**Notes on what I've found so far:**

I have been looking at Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (Rx). According to Jon Skeet's article "LINQ to Rx: second impressions" [1], he says "as soon as an observer subscribes, the observable publishes everything in the sequence to it (on a different thread, by default). Separate calls to Subscribe make the observable iterate over the sequence multiple times." This sounds like the basic idea, but I can't find any specific examples and I'm not really sure about the thread-safety of "Subject" or "AsyncSubject" yet.

**Notes on my home-grown solution:**

The structure that is delivered to subscribers looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for a set of changes that are being published.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TItem"></typeparam>
public interface IPublication<TKey, TItem>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Version of the list.
    /// </summary>
    long Version { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Items that were added or updated.
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<TItem> ChangedItems { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Keys to items that were removed.
    /// </summary>
    IEnumerable<TKey> RemovedKeys { get; }
}
```

The subscribers themselves must implement this interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interface for a subscriber that will receive IPublication{TKey, TItem} deliveries from a publisher.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TItem"></typeparam>
public interface ISubscribe<TKey, TItem>
{
    void Deliver(IPublication<TKey, TItem> pub);
}
```

And of course my generic dictionary publisher class has this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds the give subscriber to the list of subscribers and immediately publishes the
/// dictionary contents to the new subscriber. The return value may be disposed when
/// the subscriber wishes to terminate it's subscription.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="subscriber"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public IDisposable Subscribe(ISubscribe<TKey, TItem> subscriber);
```

[1]
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/19/linq-to-rx-second-impressions/

Comment: You should definitely dig deeper into Rx, and consider asking your question on the DevLabs Rx forum:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer but tedious to put into the comments so putting it here...
Not sure why are you looking at a *standard* out of box solution when your custom solution is easy to build and will work? 
Events are the simplest (and standard) way of achieving publisher-subscriber model but they are not thread-safe and also suffer from tight coupling between subscriber and publisher. MS patterns & practice group had published WCF based [pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx) but I think that you are looking for a fast in-process kind of code. Similarly, many other standard publish-subscribe solutions will be targeting application integration (ESB).
In case you didn't find any alternatives and decided to go with your custom solution then you mar refer this [artcile](http://www.dotnetarchitecthouston.com/post/The-Publish-Subscribe-Pattern-in-C-and-some-gotchas.aspx) that describes issues in implementing this design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try not to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to. Maybe I will write a blog article about my implementation. Then, I am sure to get a ton of people telling me what's wrong with it!

Comment: I'll give you the answer since your comment helped me. I put the code that I'm using here http://code.google.com/p/waynescode/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Wc.DotNetCode/Wc.Common/PubSub